# ASP.NET conditional displaying of data with SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Firstly, I apologise if this has been asked before. I've been searching for the answer for a while and seem to come up blank. It's highly likely I'm using the wrong keywords. I'm a complete nubie to ASP.NET and C# so not completely sure what to search for.

What I want to have is sections dynamically generated using conditional matching from SQL tables. So a header from a table with an ID, then all the list items in a different table that match that ID.

The markup would presumably look something like:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <% if (Eval("ID") == 1)
                { %>
            <div class="item_head">
                Bartender Roles: 
                    <ul>
                        <li>Serve Drinks</li>
                        <li>Clean Glasses</li>
                        <li>Prepare Garnish</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <% }
                if (Eval("ID") == 2)
                {%>
            <div class="item_head">
                Kitchen Porter: 
                    <ul>
                        <li>Stack Dishwasher</li>
                        <li>Keep fridges stocked</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <%}
                if (Eval("ID") == 3)
                {%>
            <div class="item_head">
                Chef: 
                    <ul>
                        <li>Prepare food</li>
                        <li>Keep fridges stocked</li>
                        <li>Rotate stock</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <%} %>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

With the Headers (Bartender roles, etc.) coming from table A and the list of roles coming from table B.

I presume the best thing to use is the Repeater, and maybe generate labels from the code behind? But I'm a bit lost after that.

Any help or advice that anyone can offer would be much appreciated. 
Apologies again if this is a duplicate question or completely simple ridiculous.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using ASP.NET and not ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Only that I'm just starting to look at it, MVC is next on the list!

Comment: In that case I would strongly suggest to look at MVC first. The learning curve is steeper. But, it a much newer technology with much better support for separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a good idea to keep your UI as simple as possible and keep your business logic on the server.

You could use `ObjectDataSource` instead of `SqlDataSource1`.
This way you could define a `Role` model on the server.

Something like:

```
public class Role
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public List<string> Responsibilities {get;set;}
}
```

Fill list of roles on the server and just enumerate that list in the UI.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>            
        <div class="item_head">
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %> :
                <ul>
                    <li><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Responsibilities") %></li> //you'll probably need another `Repeater` here
                </ul>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is a [Link](http://www.dotnetcodecentral.com/Post/116/asp-net/bind-repeater-to-objectdatasource) to an article to get you started